# How to scan a folder in Java?

Tags: java, file, directory

How can I get list all the files within a folder recursively in Java?

Comment: what do you mean by TREE? please rephrase your question if you're seeking a method to LIST all files within a folder (recursively).

Comment: @PeterPerháč this question is 4 years old.. :) thanks

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Not sure how you want to represent the tree? Anyway here's an example which scans the entire subtree using recursion. Files and directories are treated alike. Note that [File.listFiles()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28%29) returns null for non-directories.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Collection<File> all = new ArrayList<File>();
    addTree(new File("."), all);
    System.out.println(all);
}

static void addTree(File file, Collection<File> all) {
    File[] children = file.listFiles();
    if (children != null) {
        for (File child : children) {
            all.add(child);
            addTree(child, all);
        }
    }
}
```

Java 7 offers a couple of improvements. For example, [DirectoryStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#newDirectoryStream%28java.nio.file.Path%29) provides one result at a time - the caller no longer has to wait for all I/O operations to complete before acting. This allows incremental GUI updates, early cancellation, etc.

```
static void addTree(Path directory, Collection<Path> all)
        throws IOException {
    try (DirectoryStream<Path> ds = Files.newDirectoryStream(directory)) {
        for (Path child : ds) {
            all.add(child);
            if (Files.isDirectory(child)) {
                addTree(child, all);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the dreaded null return value has been replaced by IOException.

Java 7 also offers a [tree walker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/walk.html):

```
static void addTree(Path directory, final Collection<Path> all)
        throws IOException {
    Files.walkFileTree(directory, new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
        @Override
        public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs)
                throws IOException {
            all.add(file);
            return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Yeah it's like a recurring nightmare.. :P~

Comment: I have to accept this answer since I asked for the tree (I had accepted the Oscar Reyes' answer first).. even though adding one more line for the recursion wasn't that hard :)

Answer (score 23):

```
import java.io.File;
public class Test {
    public static void main( String [] args ) {
        File actual = new File(".");
        for( File f : actual.listFiles()){
            System.out.println( f.getName() );
        }
    }
}
```

It displays indistinctly files and folders.

See the methods in File class to order them or avoid directory print etc.

http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html

Answer (score 6):

You can also use the [`FileFilter`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileFilter.html) interface to filter out what you want. It is best used when you create an anonymous class that implements it:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileFilter;

public class ListFiles {
    public File[] findDirectories(File root) { 
        return root.listFiles(new FileFilter() {
            public boolean accept(File f) {
                return f.isDirectory();
            }});
    }

    public File[] findFiles(File root) {
        return root.listFiles(new FileFilter() {
            public boolean accept(File f) {
                return f.isFile();
            }});
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
public static void directory(File dir) {
    File[] files = dir.listFiles();
    for (File file : files) {
        System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
        if (file.listFiles() != null)
            directory(file);        
    }
}
```

Here `dir` is Directory to be scanned. e.g. `c:\`

Answer (score 1):

Visualizing the tree structure was the most convenient way for me :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    printTree(0, new File("START/FROM/DIR"));
}

static void printTree(int depth, File file) throws IOException { 
    StringBuilder indent = new StringBuilder();
    String name = file.getName();

    for (int i = 0; i < depth; i++) {
        indent.append(".");
    }

    //Pretty print for directories
    if (file.isDirectory()) { 
        System.out.println(indent.toString() + "|");
        if(isPrintName(name)){
            System.out.println(indent.toString() + "*" + file.getName() + "*");
        }
    }
    //Print file name
    else if(isPrintName(name)) {
        System.out.println(indent.toString() + file.getName()); 
    }
    //Recurse children
    if (file.isDirectory()) { 
        File[] files = file.listFiles(); 
        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++){
            printTree(depth + 4, files[i]);
        } 
    }
}

//Exclude some file names
static boolean isPrintName(String name){
    if (name.charAt(0) == '.') {
        return false;
    }
    if (name.contains("svn")) {
        return false;
    }
    //.
    //. Some more exclusions
    //.
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In JDK7, "more NIO features" should have methods to apply the visitor pattern over a file tree or just the immediate contents of a directory - no need to find all the files in a potentially huge directory before iterating over them.

Comment: but Is NIO faster?

Comment: @Pacerier For small directories it shouldn't make much difference. I'm even less familiar with the implementation now than I was nine years ago, but streaming NIO should be better at handling *massive* directories than reading all at once. Having said that, memory will now be several dozen times cheaper.