# How to scan a folder for files and their locations in java

Tags: java, file-io

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to scan a folder in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189094/how-to-scan-a-folder-in-java)

I want to scan a given folder for all of the files within the folder and add the locations/paths (ex: "c:/users/peter/desktop/image.jpg") to an arraylist of strings. How could i do this? Thanks for the help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Peek around in the [`java.io.File`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createTempFile%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) API. There are at least three methods which may be of use:

- [`listFiles()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28%29)
- [`isDirectory()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#isDirectory%28%29)
- [`isFile()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#isFile%28%29)

Answer (score 3):

You could try

```
File directory = new File("<Path to directory>");

String [] directoryContents = directory.list();

List<String> fileLocations = new ArrayList<String>();

for(String fileName: directoryContents) {
    File temp = new File(String.valueOf(directory),fileName);
    fileLocations.add(String.valueOf(temp));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out [File.list()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html#list%28java.io.FilenameFilter%29)