# Android: Pics in Asset Folder for Loop in Display purposes

Tags: java, android, image

I can't seem to find the exact solution for this and so I humbly ask for help in the following.

I would like to check the asset folder and have a loop to check the amount of pictures that have a prefix of "pic" as in "pic1.jpg", "pic2.jpg" and such.

Is there an efficient way to do this?  A check of the amount of pictures in the asset folder with the prefix "pic" and a gathering of the picture files so I can dynamically know how many picture to show/preview/render.

Thanks in advance and pls excuse any ignorance I might of written, still kinda green.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is an extension on this one:
[How to scan a folder in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189094/how-to-scan-a-folder-in-java)

The java.io.File API provides a method that takes a [java.io.FilenameFilter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FilenameFilter.html) and gives back a list of files and directories.

Use the FilenameFilter to provide a filter class with a method:

```
boolean accept(File dir, String name)
```

to filter the files you want. Maybe something like:

```
public class NameFilter implements FilenameFilter {

  private String prefix;

  public NameFilter(String prefix) {
    this.prefix = prefix;
  }

  public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
    return name.startsWith(prefix);
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.