# Android Image Name Randomize and Retrive

Tags: android, random, mediametadataretriever

Good day guys.I created app which captures and saves image in randomized name.I want to know how is it able to retrive Last captured image and show on imageview??i fully mean last captured because for example if i capture heaps there will be heaps names randomaly created but i want to retrive on image view last captured image with saving this randomizing feature.Can i?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [scan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/189108/987632) directory which contains images and find file with latest [modified date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#lastModified())

Comment: Sposibo ogromnoe srabotalo